# How do I change my IP Address after a specific number of loops in Python?

Tags: brute-force, ip, python

I have a for loop to brute force a Gmail account. But I've heard that Gmail's max attempts is 100. So how do I change my IP after 100 loops?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;TR: it is probably not possible what you want unless you add more illegal activity to your in several countries already illegal activity.

You cannot simply change your public visible IP address, at least not as log you want to have internet connectivity. If you are using DSL, cable, mobile phone etc your IP is assigned to you by the respective ISP. While it might change if you cut the connection to this ISP (i.e. reboot DSL/cable router or phone) the IP will not necessarily be different when you reconnect. In other networks like a public hotspot you only get a local IP address and even if you can change it it will not cause a change in the public visible IP address.

It might be that you have a public IPv6 address though. In this case you might try to change it using the respective OS command (i.e `ip addr`, `ifconfig`, `ipconfig`... - depending on your OS). But you still need to keep the same IPv6 prefix to keep connectivity and my guess is that google will just have restrictions based on prefix and not the actual IP address. And of course you would need to make your script use IPv6.

If you are in control of a botnet you can try to use it to spread the brute forcing over several IP addresses. But being in control of such a botnet is illegal in most countries.